# Музыка kivy.core.audio

Tags: python, аудио, kivy

Существует папка Musics, в которой состоят A.mp3 и B.mp3 файлы. Я хочу с помощью Kivy(kivy.core.audio) воспроизвести оба файла очередно. При использовании следующего кода, оба файла играют, но накладываются

```
files = os.listdir("Musics")
mp3files = []
for i in files:
if i[-4:] == ".mp3":
    mp3files.append(i)

for i in mp3files:

     MusicAdress = "Musics/" + i
     sound = SoundLoader.load(MusicAdress)
     if sound:
         sound.play()
```

если добавить

```
time.sleep(sound.length)
```

, то программа проигрывает так, как я хочу, но зависает.
Помогите найти решение для музыки без зависания

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time

from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Test(App):
    def play_music(self, folder_music='/Users/macbookair/Music/Metallica'):
        sounds = [f'{folder_music}/{track}' for track in os.listdir(folder_music)]
        index = 0
        lenght_track = 0
        plaing_track = None

        while True:
            if not plaing_track:
                plaing_track = SoundLoader.load(sounds[index])
                lenght_track = plaing_track.length
                plaing_track.play()
                t = time.time()
            else:
                if time.time() - t > lenght_track:
                    plaing_track = None
                    index += 1

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(
            '''
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'TEST'
        on_release: app.play_music()
'''
        )

Test().run()
```

Comment: После этого кода Пайтон говорит "не отвечает"

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time

from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.utils import asynckivy


class Test(App):
    index = 0
    lenght_track = 0
    plaing_track = None

    def play_music(self, folder_music='/Users/macbookair/Music/Metallica'):
        async def _play_music():
            while True:
                await asynckivy.sleep(0.01)
                if not self.plaing_track:
                    self.plaing_track = SoundLoader.load(sounds[self.index])
                    self.lenght_track = self.plaing_track.length
                    self.plaing_track.play()
                    t = time.time()
                else:
                    if time.time() - t > self.lenght_track:
                        self.plaing_track = None
                        self.index += 1

        sounds = [f'{folder_music}/{track}' for track in os.listdir(folder_music)]
        asynckivy.start(_play_music())

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(
            '''
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        text: 'TEST'
        on_release: app.play_music()
'''
        )

Test().run()
```

KivyMD Library - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD