# time.sleep, который можно будет отменить

Tags: python, время, break

Существует команда time.sleep(), которая должна работать, условно, 60 секунд, но с условием, что я могу ее отменить в определенный момент. Как мне break'нуть функцию?

Comment: Многопоточность/мультипроцессинг, наверное. Можете, пожалуйста, уточнить, для чего Вам это?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114292/break-interrupt-a-time-sleep-in-python

Comment: В моей программе я запускаю музыку, но чтобы две песни не налазили друг-на-друга я использую time.sleep(). Проблема в том, чтобы запустить следующую песню. Для этого мне нужно завершить фунцкию. Или подождать до конца

Comment: Нужно проверять не играет ли другой трек, а не использовать таймер.

Comment: Можно обойтись и без timer.sleep() Нужно с помощью оператора if проверить, играет ли музыка или нет. Ну а так самый тупой по моему мнению метод, это просто поместить таймер в функцию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1009946/339283

Comment: Не дубликат, но код схож

Comment: У Вас типичная [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/339283) :) Попробуйте задать новый вопрос по `kivy`, насчёт воспроизведения музыки и способа контролировать поток воспроизведения, вместо того чтобы пытаться пофиксить фикс.